# can't install codemix plugin to eclipse 2018-12

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

**OS** : `Windows 10 Enterprise`

**Eclipse version** :

```
Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers.

Version: 2018-12 (4.10.0)
Build id: 20181214-0600
```

When i trying to install the codeMix plugin to eclipse i got the following error

`An error occurred while collecting items to be installed session context was:`
`(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=). Unable to read repository at` `http://downloads.genuitec.com/downloads/products/devstyle/updates/ds20181024/plugins/com.genuitec.eclipse.core.common.platform_13.0.2.201810241355.jar. Read timed out`

Comment: That's a network problem, either temporary or permanent because of something to do with your setup. Try again later or make sure that URL is readable from outside of Eclipse.

Comment: i can download the jar : 
    http://downloads.genuitec.com/downloads/products/devstyle/updates/ds20181024/plugins/com.genuitec.eclipse.core.common.platform_13.0.2.201810241355.jar

with my browser but i still can't install the plugin

Comment: Are you using a proxy or anything beyond just the hardware and software defaults with your connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have seen this kind of problem in the past but it's rare and we haven't been able to pin down the cause. It may be intermittent. However, if you can download that file in a browser, then I suggest you do that then copy it to the plugins folder of the eclipse installation (or, if you used the eclipse installer, copy it to the .p2/pool/plugins folder under your home folder). After this, try the plugin install again.